# "mbctype.h", "stdafx.h" のコンパイルが通らない

Tags: c

数年前に組んだCのコンパイルが通らなくなってしまい困っています。
どうやら、

```
#include "mbctype.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

のコンパイルが通らないようです。

こちらの２つは使うのに何か条件があるのでしょうか？

よろしくおねがいします。

---

コメントによるとエラーメッセージは

```
$ gcc a.c
a.c:3:10: fatal error: 'mbctype.h' file not found
#include <mbctype.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

とのこと。

Comment: "数年前に組んだ"ときはMicrosoft Visual C++を使われたのでしょうか？また、今回動かしたい環境（OSとコンパイラそれぞれのバージョン）を明記してください。

Answer (score 2):

> コンパイルが通らない

であれば質問文にエラーメッセージを加えるべきですし、そのエラーメッセージで検索し原因を探るべきです。

以下は質問文から読み取れる問題について言及しますが、真の問題が何であるかはこの回答ではなくエラーメッセージを確認してください。

---

[`#include`ディレクティブ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/36k2cdd4(v=vs.120).aspx)には`引用符形式`と`山かっこ形式`があり意味が異なります。その上で[`<mbctype.h>`は`_mbbtype`関数](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/xc8tc6c1(v=vs.120).aspx)などで使いますがドキュメントにあるように`山かっこ形式`を使用しなければなりません。

`stdafx.h`というファイル名はVisual C++においてプリコンパイル済みヘッダーに用いられる既定の名称です。仮にプリコンパイル済みヘッダーに絡む問題によりコンパイルが通らないのであれば正しく構成する必要があります。
少なくともプリコンパイル済みヘッダー行`#include "stdafx.h"`より前に`#include`ディレクティブなどを記述してはいけません。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
不十分な内容で投稿してしまいすみませんでした。

#includeの山かっこと”には使い分けが正しく存在するのですね。
stdafx.hも確かに以前作った時はvisualStudioを使っていたのでstdafx.hが入っていた理由もすぐに腑に落ちました。（現在はMacのターミナルでコンパイルしています。）

今山かっこにかえてmbctype.hを通したところ、
MacBook-Pro:c_f $ gcc a.c
a.c:3:10: fatal error: 'mbctype.h' file not found
#include <mbctype.h>
              ^
1 error generated.
というエラーが出ていますが、これもおそらくwindowsse専用のライブラリだったと考えた方がよさそうですね。

ありがとうございます。

Comment: それはエラーメッセージ通り「file not found」でしょう。